# Where should I put my gem in my developing gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to understand where gems should go. I wrote a ruby script that I am trying to convert into a gem. I used bundler to create a skeleton for my gem.

Now I got 2 files 'Gemfile' and 'mygem.gemspec'.

In my Gemfile I got 2 lines saying:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in cudruby.gemspec
gemspec
```

..and in my 'mygem.gemspec' I got:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'mygem/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "mygem"
  spec.version       = Mygem::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["mygem"]
  spec.email         = ["mygem@gmail.com"]
  spec.summary       = %q{mygem}
  spec.description   = %q{mygem}
  spec.homepage      = "http://www.mygem.com"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = Dir["{lib}/**/*.rb", "bin/*", "LICENSE", "*.md"]
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.6"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

now my ruby script used to rely on 3 gems, 'facter','debugger','json'.

Where do I add these? And how?

I found this :
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Now the guy says (from the link):

*"When developing a gem, use the gemspec method in your Gemfile to avoid duplication. In general, a gem’s Gemfile should contain the Rubygems source and a single gemspec line..."*

So I left my gemspec file as it was..

I checked facter's official repository and its Gemfile is:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/master/Gemfile

..and his gemspec is:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/master/.gemspec

now why does he have his gems in the Gemfile, and nothing in the gemspec? He is just doing exactly the opposite of what I read.

Could somebody make this clear for me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important detail is that *Gemfile* and *mygem.gemspec* are Ruby files. That means you have a lot of flexibility, and can make things work in many different ways, provided `bundle` and `gem` get the data they need.  However, it is worth following the standard examples from recent documentation, the code is usually cleaner and easier to follow.

The method `gemspec` in the *Gemfile* is a convenient way of telling Bundler "this project uses the list of gems defined in the gemspec" - i.e. it avoids you needing to list dependencies twice - to enable a `bundle install` and to allow the gem to auto-install its dependencies.

*Where to add your dependencies?* At the end of the gemspec, like so:

```
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"

  # Example of one of your dependencies
  spec.add_dependency "facter", ">= 2.3.0"
end
```

Ideally you should refer the minimum version that you are certain will work bug free with your gem.

You should not use the **facter** gem as a template or example, there is something non-standard going on there. For a start the .gemspec you link is *not* facter's gemspec used to build the gem. At least in part this comes from the long history of this gem, which is nearly 10 years old. When it was first written, the toolkit of `bundler` and `gem` were nothing like they are now.

---

This is not directly asked, but worth noting for completeness:

The dependency listings are for Bundler (in the *Gemfile*) and gem building/installation (in the *.gemspec*). They do not automatically include the dependency gems in your code. So you also still need to add `require` statements to your ruby source as before.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I am still a bit confused though. So let's say somebody installs my gem, by doing 'gem install mygem', that will also install any gems in the gemspec right? what if the user has already facter but a different version?

and again in which case is the Gemfile used in a gem? when will somebody use `bundle install` for installing a gem? U use you bundle install to intall gems from a gemfile usually no?

Comment: `bundle install` is for maintaining a consistent environment for a project, and will try to meet all the version requirements from everything at the same time. Which is why a simple open-ended dependency is best. The Gemfile is used by Bundler so a gem developer can have a consistent set of dependencies to develop with. This includes coping with multiple versions installed on the system, and selecting the one to use for your project. When the gem is *installed*, the installation process does not use the `Gemfile` directly, it uses the data built into it by the `.gemspec`.